# Rollback tag for DROP table if exist condition

Tags: liquibase

What would be the rollback of droptable:

```
- changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: vikas
      changes:
            - sql:
                sql: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `adapter`
```

What should I put in rollback for the above changeset.

I am getting below error when I was trying to rollback without having rollback tag:

`Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created`

Answer (score 0):

The error

`Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created`

happens because you use raw `sql`, and not the appropriate tag for it (it would be `dropTable`), so `liquibase` doesn't know what to do with it. It can't create a `rollback`.

Also, the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) says that

> Other refactorings such as “drop table” and “insert data” have no corresponding rollback commands that can be automatically generated. In these cases, and cases where you want to override the default generated rollback commands, you can specify the rollback commands via the tag within the changeSet tag. If you do not want anything done to undo a change in rollback mode, use an empty tag.

So you'll have to create a proper `rollback` for drop table operation.